# Highcharts Bar Chart: possible to combine datapoints inside dataLabels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highcharts horizontal bar chart with two series.  Is it possible to combine the grouped data points into each data label so that they appear together, e.g. 1.00 / 2.3?

CODE:

```
var labels = [
    'AAA/Aaa',
    'AA+/Aa1',
    'AA/Aa2',
    'AA-/Aa3',
    'A+/A1',
    'A/A2',
    'A-/A3'
];
var theData = [
    {
        name: 'Company 1',
        data: [0.576,7.617,12.101,18.839,18.022,7.644,9.72]
    },
    {
        name: 'Company 2',
        data: [4.123,12.862,14.561,13.754,12.226,11.135,7.51]
    }
];
```

HIGHCHARTS CONFIG:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        var out = '<span class="col-chart-label">';
                        out +=  this.y + ' / ' + this.y;
                        out += '</span>'
                        return out;
                    },
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        },
        series:  theData,
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: labels,
            labels: {
                formatter: false,
                overflow: 'justify',
                rotation: false
            },
            reversed: true
        }
    });
});
```

The demo is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dylanmac/RungW/2/

To reiterate, there should be one data label per pair of bars with the top bar as the first value and the bottom bar as the second value, separated by "/"

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through all series and sum values for a specific category, see: http://jsfiddle.net/RungW/3/

```
                formatter: function() {
                    var out = '<span class="col-chart-label">',
                        series = this.point.series.chart.series,
                        p1 = series[0].yData[this.point.x],
                        p2 = series[1].yData[this.point.x];
                    out +=  this.y + ' / ' + (p1 + p2);
                    out += '</span>'
                    return out;
                },
```

Comment: This is close but there is still a label for each bar.  Each pair of bars (the black and the blue) should have one label with the black bar value first, followed by the blue bar value.  Note: if the black bar value is less than the blue bar, then only one label appears which is what I want. Great work so far.

Comment: That's it!  Nice work.  It was the this.point.series.chart.series that stumped me.